# EntityFramework6 with WPF update

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a EF6 data context that I'm manually binding to a form with the method below.

```
  private void GetJob(int i)
    {
        var context = new APIntegrationEntities();

        var jb = context.Jobs.Find(i);



        //tJobName.AppendText(jb.JobName.ToString());
        tId.Text = jb.Id.ToString();
        tJobName.Text = jb.JobName;
        tSourceQuery.Text = jb.SourceQuery;
        tAPI.Text = jb.API;
        tConnectionString.Text = jb.ConnectionString;
        tSheetName.Text = jb.SheetName;
        tVersion.Text = jb.VersionName;


    }
```

I'm trying to update with the following :

```
 private void bSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var context = new APIntegrationEntities();

        var jb = context.Jobs.Find(Int32.Parse(tId.Text));

        jb.JobName = tJobName.Text;
        jb.SheetName = tSheetName.Text;
        jb.SourceQuery = tSourceQuery.Text;
        jb.ConnectionString = tConnectionString.Text;
        jb.VersionName = tVersion.Text;
        jb.Id = Int32.Parse(tId.Text);
        jb.API = null;    
        context.SaveChanges();




    }
```

But I get an exception :

System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
  Source=EntityFramework

Am I using the EF correctly?   Is there a better way to bind the context to the form and process the updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using EF technically correctly but not very good from design point of view.

Exception that you have got means that you are trying to pass in job entity some illegal from database point of view data (for example `DateTime` that doesn't fit in `datetime` DB type, null in non-null column, string with length that exceeds maxlength etc.).

So you need to see exception details and figure out what particular property causes a problem and correct the the data you are passing in it.

Comment: I think it may be related to the ID. This is my primary key and in the SQL Server database it's set as an identity field which means the dbase handles the insert.  Is there a property I need to set?  I've tried just excluding it from the code but this has no effect as it's still in the model.

Comment: I readup on binding to WPF - I did this and still had the error.  I debugged a little further and it turned out to be an XML field that was causing the error.  All sorted.